# Getting windows (client coordinates) for python window

Tags: python, tkinter, coordinates, pywin32

I have loaded an image using Tkinter in Python. It opens up in a python window. If I try to get coordinates of a part of the image, it gives me coordinates relative to the python window that opened up. However, I would like to actually be able to find the client coordinates of that part of the image i.e. coordinates in relation to the actual computer screen.

I looked into using win32gui and somehow trying to get coordinates from the device context, however I could not figure out a way.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `root.winfo_rootx()` and `root.winfo_rooty()` to get the coordinates of the top left corner of the tkinter window. You can add those to the `event.x` and `event.y`to get the screen coordinates.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't come across that function in my search. Makes life easier.